# Java code to find unique key of all the table of the database

Tags: java, unique-key

I m trying to find all the unique key of all the table. And it would be vendor independent. Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean? You want to query the schema of a given table for its unique constraints?

Comment: Suppose i m trying to find out all the unique key of a table from java. So if u can, will u please tell me about the API i should use.

Answer (score 0):

As Kunal said you need to use Schema and table field checking is needed try check the schema class

Answer (score 0):

Also check DbTamer on sourceforge, with source code included.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbtamer/
It is designed to reverse engineer databases to make it easier to transport between different RDBMS but at the heart is code to iterate tables and extract table metadata into a  reusable object model.